# Python: iterating over arrays with different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, vectorization

For my work, I am trying to write a function that computes pressure on vertical levels of a grid from two inputs:

1) a `xArray.DataArray` containing at least 2 dimensions corresponding to a surface pressure field (but usually in addition one time and one ensemble member dimension, potentially more)
2) an integer corresponding to the number of vertical levels

It should return an array that is like a copy of the input array, with an extra vertical dimension.

The relevant part is this:

```
pressure = np.empty(sfc_p.shape + (vert_res,), dtype=float)

# loop 
for lev in range(vert_res):
    pressure[..., lev] = float(a_n[lev]) + float(b_n[lev]) * sfc_p.values[sfc_p.shape[:]]

return pressure
```

`sfc_p` is the input array, `vert_res` is an integer and `a_n` and `b_n` are some coefficents.

The shapes of `sfc_p` and `pressure` are:

```
(1, 51, 66, 131)  
(1, 51, 66, 131, 137)
```

respectively, as an example.

Anyway, this produces an error:
"IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1"

This obviously refers to the first dimension, but I simply cannot see whats going wrong or find out how to index correctly in such a case. I have not found any similar questions. Can anybody help me out?
If anything is unclear, I will be happy to provide further information.

Comment: I can't tell from your information which indexing operation is giving the problem.  I'd suggest running the loop with each indexing expression on a separate line, e.g. `a_n[lev]`, `b_n[lev]` etc

Comment: What is `sfc_p`?  What is `sfc_p.values[sfc_p.shape[:]]` supposed to produce?

Comment: I can reproduce the error with `a = np.ones((1, 5, 6, 13)); print(a[a.shape[:]])`

Comment: @hpaulj You mean 
`a = float(a_n[lev])`

`b = float(b_n[lev])`

`pressure[..., lev] = a + b * sfc_p.values[sfc_p.shape[:]]`
?
Sorry I have trouble understanding your suggestion.

Comment: @wwii `sfc_p` is an array containing surface pressure values on a latitude-longitude grid with additional time and ensemble dimensions.
Using `sfc_p.values[sfc_p.shape[:]]` I am trying to take every value from this array and for each of them to compute the corresponding 137 (in this case) values for the new vertical dimension.

Comment: What type of array? Numpy ndarrays don't have a `values` attribute do they?

Comment: @wwii right now I have no opportunity to double check, I will do that as soon as I can. But I am completely sure its an xarray.DataArray, which has a "values" method that returns the DataArray data as an ndarray.

Comment: Then `sfc_p.values[sfc_p.shape[:]]` is causing the error and without knowing what was intended it is hard to say how to fix it.

Comment: Anything that will help you identify exactly which indexing is giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing
`sfc_p.shape[:]`
with `:` in the line
`pressure[..., lev] = float(a_n[lev]) + float(b_n[lev]) * sfc_p.values[sfc_p.shape[:]]`
solved my problem. Thanks everyone for helping me clarify my problem!